# WPF MVVM UserControl DataBinding in XAML Not Working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, binding

I've got a user control where the DataSource is an `ObservableCollection<string>`.
If I set the DataSource of an instance of my user control via code it works

```
Chapters.DataSource = vm.ChapterList;
```

But trying to bind via ht xaml doesn't work

```
<b:ChapterStack x:Name="Chapters" DataSource="{Binding ChapterList}"></b:ChapterStack>
```

Other controls on the window are binding to the VM and displaying properly.

What do I have to do to get my usercontrol to bind via xaml?

thanks?

Comment: it ate my xaml: usercontrol x:Name="Chapters" DataSource="{Binding ChapterList}"

Comment: xaml added in by editor, thanks

Comment: Have you set the DataContext of the view to be an instance of your view model in XAML?

Comment: For that given *XAML* line to work, *vm* needs to be there as a *DataContext*. Is it? Do you get any binding errors? Check your *Output* window.

Comment: this.DataContext = _vm; //from xaml code behind

Comment: as I said the VM is bound to other controls on the window and data is dispaying properly

Comment: Have you [snooped it](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)? It's a very useful tool for debugging bindings, and WPF in general.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you defined the `DataSource` property of your `ChapterStack` control as a `Dependency Property`, because otherwise, you won't be able to bind it.

Comment: yep,  public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty

Comment: also,  public ObservableCollection<string> DataSource
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(DataSourceProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value);               
            }
        }

Comment: try debuggin the binding by adding an dummy converter and setting a break point inside it. that'll let you know what are you getting as a value. this might help

Comment: @ AbdouMoumen, found it. I was setting DataSource = new ObservableCollection<string> on the controls OnInitialized event.

Comment: @mike, if you found the solution, you should answer your own question.